# Strategy for Data Access Layer development that escalates from sqlite to SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure-sql-database, data-access-layer

I want to start a rather big project (in the end). My tool of choice is basically ASP.NET MVC/WEB Api.

I would like to develop this in the beginning by using SQLite or SQL Developer edition.

Then when i go live i would plan to go to a shared hosting by using SQL Server 2012/2014 instance.

My target is that if everything is ok to convert to cloud and Azure.

So my plan that i would like to enhance/verify is:

**Frontend:**

Since my knowledge of AngularJS/Knockout e.t.c is lomited. I will start by using the normal Jquery/web API approach and gradually i will conver tot latest best practices and standards.

**Backend:**

- Program to an Interface. I will have an interface for my DAL
- Implement different interface for my different cases (sqlite/sql server/azure e.t.c)

In order to get a fast start to building it i would start with a good domain class design and then head to *SQLite* in combination of a *light ORM (Dapper)* in order to have my logic up and running fast.

This post: [SQl Azure offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490585/developing-for-sql-azure-offline) , suggests that i could start developing for sql azure right away, but i don't know if i can afford from the beginning to go to azure.

Comment: You know that SQLite and SQL Server queries can look totally different and you may have to make some/many of them all over again?!

Comment: Yeap. I plan to use quick and dirty solution with Dapper, but i will hav ethe SAME domain classes between the different DAL implementations. I have some months between the first version and the second one that will go broadly public..

Comment: In my experience the *quick and dirty* solutions never go away and stick around forever.

Comment: @juergend , i am with you with your approach but i need something to ge tme started without a big learing curve..I would like to make a quick way through my dal to focus on my domain and then to come back to DAL...What woud that be? SQL Azure local? SQL Express? SQL Developer edition?

Comment: Although it is preferential to test on Azure from the start, it is not required. Most standard ASP.NET MVC apps will migrate without a lot of pain, just make sure you optimise for performance. If you signup for BizSpark you can get credits to use Azure for free as well.

Comment: @Craig so you just say develop locally in sql server developer edition or even sql express?

Comment: Yes, that's what I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sql Azure is basically the same as Sql Server 2014. If you start with the free SQL Server Express edition then you will have very few problems moving to SQL Azure later, especially if you use a tool like the [SQL Server Migration Wizard](https://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/) and pehaps setup a free Azure trial account so you can test as you go?

Comment: And if my first step would like to be SQL Server 2012 shared hosting (not azure)?

Comment: It depends on what database features you use as to how well it will port to Azure. The SSMWizard is excellent, but I can't guarantee it will meet your needs

Comment: So i would have to see the "common" features bewtween sql azure / sql server and decide on using them....

Comment: You can run the MigrationWizard against your local database and it will report any compatability issues. If you do this as you go along then it should be fine.

Comment: If i find stop issues in SQl server Express edition fetaures , i have 2 choices: don't use them, or convert to sql server...This would be your proposal , correct?

Comment: yes - although I think it unlikely that you will use features in SQL that are not enabled in the Azure version it would be best to check frequently then work around any issues as they come up

Answer (score 1):

You can just use your local Sql edition as mentioned by @Neil Thompson, If you are using SQL Server Database Project, there is an option to target your deployment to SQL Azure database instead of full version of Sql Server, [image: \]

I have been using above option without much problem.

Sql Federation in Azure which is I think the only major non-supported feature in on-premise/local Sql edition that you would need Sql Azure for day-to-day development/testing.